# Syntax error: player.lua:11: '=' expected near '<eof>'

Tags: lua, love2d

I have recently been learning Lua with Love2d, so I decided to start making a simple RPG. It's quite simple. The console is where you play, and the extra window is where you can see your stats, equip items, ect.
     But, I have run into a problem! Whenever I run the code, I see this `main.lua:15: '=' expected near 'else'`

I will include the code (all 3 files) below.
This is main.lua

```
function love.load()
love.graphics.setBackgroundColor( 255, 255, 255 )
require("player")

print("Enter your name")
pcStats.Name = io.read()

print("What class are you, " .. pcStats.Name .. "?")
pcStats.Class = io.read()

if pcStats.Class == "Ranger" then 
    os.execute("cls")
    pcInv.InvSpace = 10
    pcInv.Items.basicBow = Basic Bow
else
    print("Error: Invalid Class. Please restart game")
end

print("What would you like to do? CODE END")
input = io.read()
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.setColor( 0, 0, 0 )
    love.graphics.print( "Level: " .. pcStats.Level, 1, 1 )
    love.graphics.print( "Inv Space: " .. pcInv.InvSpace, 1, 20 )
    love.graphics.print( "Inv: " .. pcInv.Items, 1, 40 )
end
```

Here is player.lua This is where the game variables are stored

```
pcStats = {}
pcStats.Level = 1
pcStats.XP = nil
pcStats.Name = nil
pcStats.Class = nil
pcStats.Atk = nil   
pcStats.Def = nil

pcInv = {}
pcInv.InvSpace = nil
pcInv.Items.testsword = testing sword
```

And last but not least, here is the conf.lua used for love2d

```
function love.conf(t)
    t.modules.joystick = true  
    t.modules.audio = true      
    t.modules.keyboard = true   
    t.modules.event = true    
    t.modules.image = true      
    t.modules.graphics = true   
    t.modules.timer = true     
    t.modules.mouse = true      
    t.modules.sound = true     
    t.modules.thread = true
    t.modules.physics = true    
    t.console = true          
    t.title = "Lua RPG Alpha v0.0.1"        
    t.author = "Zach Herzer"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 15 is this:

```
    pcInv.Items.basicBow = Basic Bow
```

`Basic Bow` isn't valid Lua code. I am pretty sure you meant something else - perhaps a string?

```
pcInv.Items.basicBow = "Basic Bow"
```

---

While we're at it,

```
pcInv.Items.testsword = testing sword
```

has a similar problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks but now i'm getting an error that says
Error: player.lua:11: attempt to index field 'Items' (a nil value)

Comment: @ZachHerzer You need to initialize `Items` before you can index it. `pcInv.Items = {}` would be enough.

Comment: thanks so much! i got my error solves in less that 30 minutes! 
+1

Comment: @Zach If this answer helped you be sure to press the green checkmark next to it! This helps future readers with a similar problem get their answer quicker!